# If $s_n$ is a sequence that converges, then show that if $s_n \ge a$ for all but finitely many $n$, then $\lim s_n \ge a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

This question has been asked multiple times, but none of them use the same method I have used to attempt the proof.
Here's what I did:

$s_n$ is a convergent sequence. Thus
$$\left|s_n - s\right| \lt \epsilon$$
Reverse triangle inequality:
$$\left|s_n\right| - \left|s\right| \le \left|s_n - s\right| \lt \epsilon$$
$$\text{or, } a \le\left|s_n\right| \lt \epsilon + \left|s\right|$$
$$\text{or, } a \lt \epsilon + |s| \text{ for arbitrary } \epsilon$$
$$\text{therefore, } a < \lim s_n$$
The problem here is that I am getting $a \lt \lim s_n$, whereas I should be getting $a \le \lim s_n$. Please tell me what I did wrong here.

Comment: First of all, $a < \lim s_n$ implies $a\leq \lim s_n$, so if you are happy with your proof, you are done.  However, I would recommend establishing some understandable notation and appealing to definitions when writing proofs.  For example, what is $s$ and $\epsilon$? For which $n$ does the inequality $|s_n-s|<\epsilon$ holds? Finally, $a<\epsilon + |s|$ for any $\epsilon>0$ does not imply $a<|s|$. Etc etc

Comment: @rafexiap there is a proof for $\lim \inf s_n = \lim s_n = \lim \sup s_n$(if $\lim s_n$ is defined), which concludes from $\lim \sup s_n \le s + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ that $\lim \sup s_n \le s$, where $s$ is the limit of the function. Can I not extend that same argument here to say that $a < \epsilon + |s|$ implies $a < |s|$?

Comment: consider that $x < x+\epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$, but clearly $x\not < x$